# Creating MXD From Standalone ArcPy Snippet?

Tags: arcpy, mxd

Is it possible to create some MXD from a list using Arcpy stand alone snippet? For example if I have a list like

```
counties = ['Benton', 'Caroll','Polk','Scot']
```

can I run a code like

```
import arcpy

for mxd in counties 
    MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\\"+ mxd+ '.mxd')
    MXD.save()
```

Comment: No, arcpy cannot create a new MXD. I create an empty doc with ArcMap, mark the file read-only, drop it in a temp folder within the app, then use SaveAs to write the new doc..

Comment: Wow! I like this naughty idea! ;-)

Comment: Supported by https://community.esri.com/ideas/7073 I use a similar procedure for other template objects; For your information see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing about getting the path of the script that is executing, keep your blank MXD with the script, that way your script will be more robust about being moved.

Comment: Use the same trick with Group Layers, but be careful that the folder is empty when you save it (lest the contents be included).